# Is there something like preparedStatement.setDefault()?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

If I have a statement like:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, name, description, etc_a, etc_b)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

It's passed into a `PreparedStatement`. Sometimes I want to specify an id, and sometimes I want to use the database's `DEFAULT` for id, which is the next unused id value.

Is there a way I can tell the `PreparedStatement` (PS) to use `DEFAULT` for one of the values without having a second PS with `DEFAULT` in the place of the first `?`?

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: @juergend That is wrong. If nulls are allowed for the column, they will be NULL rather than DEFAULT. If nulls are not allowed for the column, and exception will be thrown when the PS is executed.

Comment: Don't pass that particular parameter.

Comment: Worst case, set up 2 PreparedStatements.  One with id, like in your question, and one without id.  The insert without id should use the default value for id.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Tried that already. I get an exception from the PS telling me that a parameter didn't have a value specified. GilbertLeBlanc - This is the exact case I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Because you still mention in the prepared statement. Use separate prepared statement WITHOUT that parameter, no mentioning between field names and no matching "?", at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately PgJDBC doesn't currently do what you want. You have to use a literal `DEFAULT` keyword. There's no way to do it with a parameter.

[The team I work for](http://www.2ndquadrant.com/) is developing an enhancement to fix this that'll hopefully make it into a PgJDBC release soon. You'll then be able to use `setObject(...)` with a special placeholder instance to indicate that you want `DEFAULT`.